# Custom CSS :: Blocks

Tags: moodle

I had been developed a custom block 'Colleges', along with a stylesheet: styles.css within the block.
by using moodle2.8+

styles.css

```
.block_colleges .header { display:none; }
.block_colleges .title h2 { color:#fff; font-size:18px; font-weight:bold; margin:-5px; }
.block_colleges { float:left; margin-left:5px; width:317px !important; }
.block_colleges .content { border:1px solid lightgray; border-top-left-radius:10px; border-top-right-radius:10px; border-bottom-left-radius:10px; border-bottom-right-radius:10px; margin-top:0px; border:0px solid #a6c9e2; padding:0px; min-height:220px; }
```

The above css should be applicable for only students and teachers...and for admin, the css shouldn't be applicable i.e., a moodle block format design.

Can we create block::custom css, different for student/teacher and admin.

Answer (score 0):

A file named **styles.css** in the main directory of a Moodle block will automatically be cached and used on the page. There's no way to load different CSS based on role that I know of.

If you want to show different CSS for different roles, perhaps you can have role specific CSS classes, then change the classes in your markup based on the logged in user's role.

**For example:**

```
#block_colleges.student .header { display:**none**; }
#block_colleges.teacher .header { display:**block**; }
```

In your **block_colleges.php** file, you could write something like:

```
if (is_siteadmin())
{
    // class = admin
}
else
{
    // class = student
}
```

This is how I would do it.